# Should I use recursion to answer this instead of a loop?

Tags: java, loops, recursion

A man begins a car trip to visit his in-laws. The total distance is 60 miles, and he starts off at a speed of 60 miles per hour. After driving exactly 1 mile he loses some of his enthusiasm for the journey, and (instantaneously) slows down to 59 miles per hour. After traveling another mile, he again slows to 58 miles per hour. This continues, progressively slowing by 1 mile per hour for each mile traveled until the trip is complete.

Now I do know what to do I believe,

I'm to find the speed he is traveling for each mile and calculate how long it takes him to travel 1 mile, and then I'm to add all the values to reach the answer.

I was attempting to write an equation to do this, but I think a loop or recursion would be simpler.

Can someone just point me in the right direction in making this program give me the correct answer. On paper I can just add and get 4.6 hours (the right answer) easily, but its just a bit difficult to write a recursive program (or maybe I SHOULD use a loop?)

Comment: use a loop for your case.

Answer (score 0):

For this exact problem, there is not much complexity and resource issues. You can use either of the solution. I guess loop will be simpler in this case. That being said recursive won't be complex either.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively it would be:

```
public static double run(double miles, double speed){
    if(miles <= 1){
        return 1/speed;
    }
    return 1/speed + run(miles-1, speed-1);
}
```

This will give you the number of hours (as a double) that it takes (given that miles are in mile units, and speed in miles per hour)

Modify accordingly for the data types you would like

If you would like an even smaller code block using a ternary operator:

```
public static double run(double miles, double speed){
    return 1/speed + (miles <= 1 ? 0 : run(miles-1, speed-1));
}
```